# Anything to do upon first contact?

Tags: civilization-5

Is there anything I should try to do upon first contact with another civilization's leader? Whatever I'm trying is usually rejected, i.e. nobody wants to enter pacts, do open borders or anything else of use right away. Should I do anything but click on *Goodbye*?

Answer (score 7):

I just click Goodbye. I have never had another civ want to do anything until a few turns have passed.